# Limit of $\frac{\binom{2n}{n+2}n^{n-2}(n.(n+1) \cdots 2n)}{n^{2n}}$ as $n\to \infty$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Limit of $$\frac{\binom{2n}{n+2}n^{n-2}(n.(n+1) \cdots 2n)}{n^{2n}}$$ as $n\to \infty$

Does it go to zero?

WolframAlpha says it does, but it does not make sense since

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\binom{2n}{n+2}n^{n-2}n!}{n^{2n}}\rightarrow \infty. 
\end{equation*}

Is Wolfram wrong?

Comment: For me, it is going to $\infty$. Check what you typed. The logarithm of the expression seems to vary linearly with $n$. Use Mann comment with Stirling approximation. It could help.

Comment: This is what your limit looks like after bit manipulation $\frac{1}{n} \times \frac{(2n!)^2}{n^{n+1}\times (n-1)! \times (n+2)! \times (n-2)!}$ Assuming one in title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *equivalents*:

First rewrite the expression:
$$\frac{\dbinom{2n}{n+2}n^{n-2}n!}{n^{2n}}=\frac{(2n)!\,n!}{(n+2)!\,(n-2)!}\cdot\frac1{n^{n+2}}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!}\cdot\frac n{n+2}\cdot\frac1{n^{n+2}} $$
Now use *Stirling's formula*:
$$\frac{(2n)!}{n!}\sim_\infty\dfrac{2\sqrt{\pi n}\,2^{2n}\Bigl(\dfrac{n}{\mathrm e}\Bigr)^{2n}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\Bigl(\dfrac{n}{\mathrm e}\Bigr)^n}=\sqrt 2\,\Bigl(\dfrac{4}{\mathrm e}\Bigr)^n n^n$$
whence
$$\frac{\dbinom{2n}{n+2}n^{n-2}n!}{n^{2n}}\sim_\infty\frac{\sqrt2}{n^2}\Bigl(\dfrac{4}{\mathrm e}\Bigr)^n\to +\infty$$
since, as $\dfrac4{\mathrm e}>1$, we have $n^2=o\biggl(\Bigl(\dfrac{4}{\mathrm e}\Bigr)^n\biggr)$.

Comment: In the last line of your proof was a typo...you need $n^2$ instead of $\frac1{n^2}$...+1

Comment: Oh, yes! I happento have typos more than often. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

Ya its actually zero.

Proof :- $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(2n)!n!}{(n+2)!(n-2)!n^2n^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n+2)!n^n}*\frac{n(n-1)}{n^2} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{(n+2)!n^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)...(2n)}{n^n} = 0$$ as the power of n in numerator is less than that of denominator.

Comment: yes, but in the numerator there is $n(n+1)...2n$ and not n!

Comment: The last paragraph is not true...because the coefficients in the numerator are changing...